# Trying to use axios, vuejs and a dummy api for my chartjs and googlecharts (get requests only)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, chart.js

I am trying to use axios in combination with a link containing this data: { "2015": 226, "2016": 152, "2017": 259, "2018": 265, "2019": 275}, written in JSON.

I want to implement those data, the year for example: 2017 and the revenue: 259 in this chart:

```
//BARCHART
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Vergangenheit', //Vergangenheit = Past
        data: [226, 152, 259, 265, 0],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(110, 205, 126, 1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(110, 205, 126, 1)',
        borderWidth: 1,
      }
    ]
  },

  options: {
    responsive: true,
    responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    aspectRatio: 2,
    oneResie: null,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

});
```

With the combination of vue and axios a get request should look like this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#get',
  data: {
    messages: [],
    message: ""
},
mounted: function () {
    this.getMessages(); // get all messages automatically when the page is loaded
},
methods: {
    getMessages: function() {
        axios.get('(hiddenhttps:/api/GewinnNachJahr')
            .then( (res) => {
                this.messages = res.data;
                console.log(response.data)
            })
    },
}
});
```

I don't want any button to press for the get request, it should always get that data when reloading the page. I already tried the a few code snippets from stackoverflow, the official axios github don't help me at all.

So to summarize i want that axios getrequest on my http datas, then saving and sorting this data and implementing it in my chart.js barchart. I think its enough to just working withing my java.js.

I apologize for the time and effort involved. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement chart.js into your vue app. I have created this code it should work.

```
   var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#get",
  data: {
    messages: [],
    message: "",
    labels: [],
    data_set: [],
    barChart: ""
  },
  mounted: function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    this.barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Vergangenheit", //Vergangenheit = Past
            data: this.data_set,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(110, 205, 126, 1)",
            borderColor: "rgba(110, 205, 126, 1)",
            borderWidth: 1
          }
        ]
      },

      options: {
        responsive: true,
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        aspectRatio: 2,
        oneResie: null,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    });
  },
  created: function() {
    this.getMessages(); // get all messages automatically when the page is loaded
  },
  methods: {
    getMessages: function() {

      axios
        .get(
          "https://webenggroup06ln3.free.beeceptor.com/zalando/api/GewinnNachJahr"
        )
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data);
          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(res.data)) {
            this.labels.push(key);
            this.data_set.push(value);
          }
          this.$nextTick(function() {
            this.barChart.update();
          });
        });
    }
  }
});
```

the `for` loop splits your key and your value seperate and then it pushes it into the data array. After everything is pushed inside the array the chart just needs to get updated with `this.barChart.update()`

Comment: I put in my original api now, i tryied your code on an empty html and js file as well as in my work in progress code, i cant get it to work properly, check my detailed answer for more information.

Comment: it says too many requests. so i followed the link https://beeceptor.com/pricing and i guess you reached your limit of 50 requests per day ?

Comment: i have update it, it works fine. copy and paste it it should work

Comment: in the `.then()` block i removed accedently this line of code `this.messages = res.data;` just add it if you need it

Comment: for example, if i have 2 data sets and 1 label, like revenue 2017 is 100$ and profit is 10$, how do i set this up?

Answer (score 1):

`mounted` or `created` is the correct place to implement bootstrapping logic for this case. However your code has some problems in definitions and typo:

- `'(hiddenhttps:/api/GewinnNachJahr'`: the initial parenthesis should be omitted
- `console.log(response.data)`: `response` should become `res` for matching callback parameter.

See a working example with a dummy api call and how it loads the data:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    messages: [],
    message: ""
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getMessages(); // get all messages automatically when the page is loaded
  },
  methods: {
    getMessages() {
      axios.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
        .then((res) => {
          this.messages = res.data;
          console.log(res.data)
        })
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="m in messages">{{JSON.stringify(m)}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When i'm using the Postman Applikation i can do a GET Request and get those JSON Data: {
    "2015": 226,
    "2016": 152,
    "2017": 259,
    "2018": 265,
    "2019": 275
} but no key in the header, it that maybe the problem? i copy pasted your code, just changed the link (also tryied to use your link) but i can not get the list <ul> filled with data. scripts are working fine as the {{JSON.stringify(m)}} appears for a second and disappears again. any other suggestions why your solutions don't work for me?

Comment: i tryied your code with an empty html and js file, and that works than, seems so be the rest of my code that causes a problem. thank you for your help vahdet!

Comment: that doenst work because you get an Object as response and not an array. his response is an array and he is assigning it to messages and with v-for he can loop through. `JSON.stringify` is unnecessary because axios do it for you already

Comment: @lfaruki As the OP hides the original api, I used a dummy one. Stringifying is for also for the same dummy/simplicity reasons. If we have the real api, we can use it anyway. And `res.data` is what response body is: array if array, single object if single object. Alas, arrays are also objects, all in all.

Comment: I cannot see any edits on the question, indeed. Please elaborate by editing the question itself whenever necessary. This way, the community can access the latest version at one glance and it becomes clean.